# Why does my code not execute the outcome of my simple rock, paper, scissors game? PYTHON3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Here is my code, for some reason the outcome of the game is not displayed and I don't know why, can anyone explain how I can make the desired outcome be executed. I have tried messing around with my code for a while, if you know how to fix this can you teach me so that next time I won't make the same mistake. Thank you.

```
import random

Rock= 0
Paper = 1
Scissors = 2
Quest = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?")
print("You choose",Quest)
AI = random.randint(0,2)

#What the A.I Chooses
if AI == 0:
    print("A.I Chooses Rock")

if AI == 1:
    print("A.I Chooses Paper")

if AI == 2:
    print("A.I Chooses Scissors")

# if you draw:
if AI == 0 and Quest == Rock:
    print("So, you draw")
if AI == 1 and Quest == Paper:
    print("So, you draw")
if AI == 2 and Quest == Scissors:
    print("So, you draw")
# Rock Possible Outcomes
if AI == 0 and Quest == Paper:
    print("So, you loose")
if AI == 0 and Quest == Scissors:
    print("So, you win")
# paper Possible Outcomes
if AI == 1 and Quest == Rock:
    print("So, you loose")
if AI == 1 and Quest == Scissors:
    print("So, you win")
#Scissors Possible Outcomes
if AI == 2 and Quest == Paper:
    print("So, you loose")
if AI == 2 and Quest == Rock:
    print("So, you win")
```

Comment: Rock, paper, scissors should be inside quotes in if statements as they are strings

Answer (score 1):

If you are entering the *words* relating to your choice, you should be aware that they will not be considered equal:

```
>>> if 0 == 'rock': print('match')
# no output
```

If you are entering the *numbers* relating to your choice, they will still be treated as a string (just a different string) and they will not be considered equal:

```
>>> if 0 == '0': print('match')
# no output
```

What you need to do is make sure you compare a number with a number:

```
>>> if 0 == int('0'): print('match')
match
```

You can do that by ensuring you enter the number-y string for your choice *and* turn it in to a number for comparison:

```
Quest = int(input("0 = rock, 1 = paper, 2 = scissors?"))
```

You *could* also just use the strings assuming that you compare against `"rock"` (the string) rather than `rock` the number. But, if you look at the code below, you'll see numbers can make your code a lot smaller.

---

If you want a more *succinct* implementation, you might want to consider this one:

```
import random
random.seed()
choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

# Make sure user enters valid choice.

choice = ''
while choice not in choices:
    choice = input('Rock, paper, or scissors? ').lower()
print('You chose', choice)
you = choices.index(choice)

# AI just makes random choice.

ai = random.randint(0,2)
print('AI chose', choices[ai])

# Draw if both same, otherwise three scenarios in which player wins,
# otherwise AI wins.

if you == ai:
    print('A draw')
elif (you == 0 and ai == 2) or (you == 1 and ai == 0) or (you == 2 and ai == 1):
    print('You win')
else:
    print('AI wins')
```

It gets everything to a number as quickly as possible, to ensure comparisons are a simpler matter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but why can I not simply use an AND gate in my code?

Comment: @ErenUcar, you *can,* assuming you're actually comparing the right things. As per my answer that is not currently the case, you compare a string against a number.

Answer (score 0):

As Rohit Raj [mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643783/why-does-my-code-not-execute-the-outcome-of-my-simple-rock-paper-scissors-game/54644307#comment96079122_54643783):

> Rock, paper, scissors should be inside quotes in if statements as they are strings

placing them inside quotes solved the problem.